# Are there any items to get use of the ability Contrary?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

As [Malamar](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Malamar) is only weak to two types, it would be good to give him some Leftovers. But as this item is already been hold by another Pokémon of mine - and I don't want to take items twice - I'm searching for another item.

I would like to get his ability [Contrary](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Contrary_%28Ability%29) to use. So if a stat of Malamar is being increased, it's decreased instead - and vice-versa.

So I started asking myself how I can get advantage of Contrary. Are there any items that decrease a stat every round for example? Or a compareable item like [Weakness Policy](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Weakness_policy#Weakness_Policy) that instead decreases stats on event? Or are there better options?

My question is: **Which items are best to use with Contrary?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only [negative items](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/In-battle_effect_item#Negative_effect_on_holder) are Flame Orb, Toxic Orb, Sticky Barb, Iron Ball and Ring Target, but none of these lowers a stat every round in battle.

Iron Ball actually reduces a Pokemon's speed by 50%, but it won't trigger **Contrary** ability.

Comment: Tested Iron Ball on play.pokemonshowdown.com - no effect of Contrary. Well, then I guess you're right. :)

Comment: Some guy has to test it on the real Nintendo game, as pkmnShowdown may be based on predictions. But I don't think there is much hope.

Comment: I think it's only a "mathematical" reduction, you don't see the animation of the speed fell in-game, so Contrary can't be activated.

Comment: If you play doubles, have your partner use a stat dropping move on it, like Feather Dance

Comment: @Robotnik I use Bulldoze - it lowers the opponents' Speed while raising Malamar's ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Nice one, but Malamar still receives damage

Comment: @pinckerman True, but if you've already fired off a Superpower, and/or have a primarily Special Attacker use Bulldoze for its effect rather than for damage, then it can become *very* cheap.